# cy.fixture is not executing inside a loop

Tags: cypress

I am trying to load different JSON based on the values I get from the array.

```
for(let reqObj of reqArray) {
cy.fixture(`${reqObj.jsonURL`}).then((jsnObj)=>{
console.log(jsnObj)
})
}
```

But the cy.fixture is not executing. No error is shown in the console like json files not found .

Comment: Try doing it with the `cypress.env` method and see if it uploads then. That will tell you if you are using the loop correctly.

Comment: Yes worked with cypress.env . I guess it did not worked inside for loop as cy.fixture returns a promise(async)  by the time it returns the loop already went ahead